# Sum datetime in MySQL rows

Tags: php, mysql

**Question:**

Is it possible to group all rows in MySQL and sum the hours?

```
Starttime - type:datetime, Stoptime - type:datetime
```

**Data**

```
Starttime, stoptime
2016-10-25 09:00:00, 2016-10-29 17:00:00
2016-11-26 09:00:00, 2016-11-26 17:00:00
2016-11-30 09:00:00, 2016-11-30 17:00:00
2017-01-28 09:00:00, 2017-01-28 17:45:00
```

The code below sums all the hours between 2016-10-25 and 2017-01-28. I need it to sum all the time on every row and then all rows together. Is it possible to sum this in MySQl or am I bound to PHP?

```
SELECT 
MIN(starttime), 
MAX(stoptime), 
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stoptime, starttime))/3600) AS total_hours 
FROM mytable WHERE id = 1219
```

Comment: seems correct  .. what's the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that I want (if possible) to sum up all the hours in MySQL. First row by row and then all the rows together. I can do this by using both MySQL and PHP. But I wonder if it is possible to do this more efficient using just MySQL.

Comment: what is the schema of the `mytable` table? If you need the total hours for all rows, why do you have the `where id = 1219` clause? If `id=1219` just corresponds to one row, then what is the meaning of `min` and `max` of just 1 row / column value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum up all differences, you don't need `min(starttime)` or `max(stoptime)`, just use `sum` of [`timestampdiff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), e.g.

```
select sum(timestampdiff(hour, starttime, stoptime))
from mytable
```

If you want fractional hours, keep `time_to_sec(...) / 3600` as in your question

```
select sum(time_to_sec(timediff(stoptime, starttime)) / 3600)
from mytable
```

See also [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49bd0/6/0)